# Python Shuffle two arrays of numbers so that adjacent ones differ

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, shuffle

I have two different arrays with the same qty of values in them(values have duplicates):

```
first = [1,1,2,2,3,3]
second = [1,1,2,2,3,3]
```

I want to shuffle these two arrays in order that adjacent values wouldn't be repeated in every direction(left,right,up,down)

example:

```
first =  [1,2,1,3,2,3]
second = [2,1,3,1,3,2]
```

So the first value from the first array "1" differ from below value "2' and from the value "2" that is next to it. This sequence is respected for every value in both arrays.

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if all values are equal? I mean what happens if the arrays cannot meet the expected sequence?

Comment: Are the lists always sorted at the start and is a possible solution guaranteed?

Comment: Hi Dani! I understand your concern.

If the value is such repetitive, for example:

first = [1,1,1,1,2,3]
second = [1,1,1,1,3,3]

i would like to shuffle values just as much as possible and then go repetetive:

output:
first      = [1,2,1,3,1,1]
second = [3,1,3,1,1,1]

Comment: Hey Michael,
The arrays could appear in any way/order.

Answer (score 1):

We need two result arrays R1 and R2

Step 1: Get distinct values from your 1st array
in the example case 2,1,3 ;

Step 2 : Arrange in ascending order [1,2,3] repeat the sequence untill the length of the list is exhausted [1,2,3,1,2,3]
This is R1

Step 3:
R2 = R1 shifted to the right by 1 index;
R2= [2,3,1,2,3,1]

This is a solution